# Min cut using matlab cvx

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization, cvxopt

I am trying to detect communities using binary min cut on users' graph. For this purpose I am trying to use a variant of Fiedler method as shown in [this](http://library.calstate.edu/sanfrancisco/articles/record?id=FETCH-acm_primary_23396931) paper. This is how they have formalized it:

[image]

Now, I am trying to do this using the CVX package in matlab. Here is my code:

```
tou = ((beta/ (e' * pi1 * e)) * tou1) + (((1 - beta) / (e' * pi2 * e)) * tou2);
n = 6;
cvx_begin
    variable y(n)
    minimize( y' * tou * y )
    subject to
        y' * pi1 * y == e' * pi1 * e
        y' * pi2 * y == e' * pi2 * e
        y' * pi1 * e == 0
        y' * pi2 * e == 0
cvx_end
```

But it is showing me the following error:

```
Disciplined convex programming error:
Invalid constraint: {convex} == {real constant}

Error in ==> cvx.eq at 12
b = newcnstr( evalin( 'caller', 'cvx_problem', '[]' ), x, y, '==' );

Error in ==> fiedler at 16
y' * pi1 * y == e' * pi1 * e
```

Here A1 is a matrix defined as follows:

```
A1 = [0 3 2 0 0 0; 3 0 3 1 0 0; 2 3 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0 4 2; 0 0 0 4 0 3; 0 0 0 2 3 0];
```

Similarly A2 = A1.

And pi1 is a matrix is a diagonal matrix whose value is equal to sum of all the values of A1 in that particular row. Doing so I get

```
pi1 = [5 0 0 0 0 0; 0 7 0 0 0 0; 0 0 5 0 0 0; 0 0 0 7 0 0; 0 0 0 0 7 0; 0 0 0 0 0 5];
```

Similary, pi1 = pi2.

And tou1 = pi1 - A1, and tou2 = pi2 - A2.

Can someone point out what exactly I am doing wrong. It would be of great help. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

This issue is that your constraint

```
  y'* pi1 * y == alpha
```

(where `alpha = e'*pi1*e` ) is not a convex constraint. Consider the two dimensional case where size(y) = [2 1] and pi1 is the identity, then your constraint above is

```
       y(1)^2 + y(2)^2 == alpha
```

This is equivalent to requiring y to lie on the radius of a circle. This is not convex constraint.

CVX is designed for *disciplined* convex optimization. This means that you must build your model up from primitives in a way that ensures the model is convex. Since your model includes a constraint that is not convex CVX issues the error: "Disciplined convex programming error".

It also tells you the problem: "Invalid constraint {convex} == {real constant}". That tells you that you are trying to constrain a convex function to be equal to a constant.

If you want to solve this model with CVX you will need to reformulate the model to be convex. If you can't reformulate it, you might try using a nonlinear (noncovex) solver. For example, [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) included in MATLAB should be able to handle this constraint. Note that `fmincon` is designed for fairly small scale models, for large scale nonlinear noncovex models you probably want to use a solver like [SNOPT](http://www.sbsi-sol-optimize.com/asp/sol_product_snopt.htm) or [KNITRO](http://www.ziena.com/knitro.htm).

Comment: @Shai quadprog requires the constraints be linear, these constraints are non-convex quadratic, so the OP will need to use a solver that can handle nonlinear constraints.

Answer (score 1):

For the original problem, the equality constraints can be usually relaxed by replacing equal sign (=) with <=. Most of the time, the solution will satisfy the equality constraints (but not guaranteed).

The original problem can e relaxed as follows:

```
tou = ((beta/ (e' * pi1 * e)) * tou1) + (((1 - beta) / (e' * pi2 * e)) * tou2);
n = 6;
cvx_begin
 variable y(n)
 minimize( y' * tou * y )
 subject to
     y' * pi1 * y <= e' * pi1 * e
     y' * pi2 * y <= e' * pi2 * e
     y' * pi1 * e <= 0
     y' * pi2 * e <= 0
cvx_end
```

You need to verify if the solution (or pick one of the solutions) satisfies the equality constraint.
Hope it works for the OP.